# unable to connect to mysql database in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm facing this problem for few days now. I'm trying to connect to my `MySQL` on `Ubuntu` machine. But I'm not getting this thru. Please see the following commands that I ran and the error messages.

```
root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# mysql start
```

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
>   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

```
root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# mysql -uroot -p
```

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
>       Enter password: 
>       ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

```
root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# mysqld
```

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
>   150821 11:34:38 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of
>   the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
>
> 150821 11:34:38 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 150821 11:34:38 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

```
root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# mysql restart
```

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
>   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

```
root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
>   Enter password:  mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
>   error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)' Check that mysqld is running and
>   that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

Could anyone please tell what is the issue. It seems to me that DB has been corrupted. If yes, then how can I recover? TIA.

Comment: service mysqld restart and then tried?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is very clearly explained in the warning message, it is ignoring your `my.cnf`.

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored

Try executing the following, and then restarting the server

```
chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/my.cnf
chmod 600 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

This will set the owner of the file to *mysql* and the permissions *600* will give only the user *mysql* access to read and write to the file, it will disallow access to all other users.

Comment: I have down this.. and now file permission looks alike .. `-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 3579 Aug 21 09:54 /etc/mysql/my.cnf` ... Do I need to restart mysql now? `mysql restart` or something else?

Comment: That is how it should look, now do as you said, `service mysql restart` and let me know how it works.

Comment: it says ...  `stop: Unknown job: mysql 
start: Unknown job: mysql` :(

Comment: I executed show databases command, and it says ... `root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# show databases
The program 'show' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install nmh
root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# `

Comment: without service.. it says... `root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# mysql restart
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)`

Comment: Hmm, then start the server using `mysqld` or `mysqld_safe`, and then try logging in using `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87552/discussion-between-indra-prakash-tiwari-and-matt-clark).

Comment: still I did not get any solution. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6):

Check owner of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` that it's actualy `mysql` and do a

```
chmod go -rw /etc/mysql/my.cnf
service mysql restart
```

It's obviously totally ignoring whats configured and trying to connect through local socket which is probably not open.

Comment: fixing file permission didn't help

Comment: getting error -- test@ipadtest:~$ mysql restart
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this Error By the Below Commands :-

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
```

After That Do the 2nd Command:-

```
sudo chmod 600 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
```

It Resolve Me. Anyone face this problem try once with above cmd.